# Get unrotated position of a rectangle.

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

I'm struggeling with the following problem.

[image: Rotated rectangle]

I have a rotated rectangular. The following values are known. The size of the rect, the angle the rect is rotated by and the position of point A. The given angle will always be positive.

[image]

How can i obtain the unrotated position of point A?

Comment: What a cute butterfly!

Comment: We are rotating about which point? The one with the arrow in it?

Comment: @imranfat The center of the rect, however i don't have those coordinates. Can i distill those from the given values somehow?

Comment: @Rebecca Haha i guess it is cute ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the line between the A and the orange (x) to have length $ L $, and angle $ \theta $ with respect to the horizontal. Let the position of A be the coordinates $ (a_x,a_y) $. Let the other dimension be $ W $.

The center of the rectangle has coordinates $ ( c_x, c_y) =  (a_x,a_y) + \frac{L}{2} (-\cos\theta, \sin\theta) + \frac{W}{2} (\sin \theta, \cos \theta) $. Then the position of A after rotation is then $ (a_x',a_y') =  (c_x,c_y) + \frac{L}{2} (-1,0) + \frac{W}{2} (0,1) $.

Comment: Thanks! You mean the position of A before rotation right?

Comment: @Baijs: It depends whether you think of the first picture rotating to become the second, or the other way around.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: unrotatedAx = (cos * (width / 2) - sin * (height / 2) + rotatedAx) - (width / 2)
unrotatedAy = (sin * (width / 2) + cos * (height / 2) + rotatedAy) - (height / 2)